# Python gets the wrong encoding for UTF-8 characters?

Tags: python, unicode, escaping, urllib2

I'm trying to fetch text with special characters from a website, and the string Python returns is therefore full of "\x" characters.
However, it seems that the encoding is wrong.
For example, when fetching :

```
th =urllib2.urlopen('http://norse.ulver.com/dct/zoega/th.html')
```

the line at level `<h1>` of the webpage should contain the letter "Þ", which has byte number C39E and Unicode code DE according to http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm

Instead, I get

```
'<h1>\xc3\x9e</h1>'
```

with the byte number split in two, so that when writing the line to a file and then opening it with a Unicode encoding, I get "Ãž" instead of "Þ".

How can I force Python to encode such a character as `\uC39E` or `\xde` instead of `\xc3\x9e` ?

Comment: Sounds like everything is working as it should, but *you* are mixed up. Don't worry; this is fairly common. Don't use a Latin-1 or code page 1251 tool to examine UTF-8 (or go right ahead; but understand what you are looking at).

Comment: Terminology correction: 0xC3 0x9E is the UTF-8 *encoding* of [U+00DE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00de/index.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the correct UTF-8 *byte* encoding of U+00DE and it takes two bytes to represent it (`\xc3` and `\x9e`), but you need to decode it to Unicode to see the Unicode codepoint.  In Python 3 `ascii()` will show non-ASCII code points as escape codes:

```
>>> print(ascii(b'<h1>\xc3\x9e</h1>'.decode('utf8')))
'<h1>\xde</h1>'
```

The above is a Unicode string showing the correct Unicode codepoint.  Displaying it in Python 3:

```
>>> b'<h1>\xc3\x9e</h1>'.decode('utf8')
'<h1>Þ</h1>'
```

If you use the wrong encoding to decode you get different Unicode codepoints. In this case U+00C3 and U+017E.  `\xc3` is an *escape code* in a Unicode string for Unicode codepoints < U+0100 whereas `\u017E` is one for codepoints < U+10000:

```
>>> print(ascii(b'<h1>\xc3\x9e</h1>'.decode('cp1252')))
'<h1>\xc3\u017e</h1>'
>>> b'<h1>\xc3\x9e</h1>'.decode('cp1252')
'<h1>Ãž</h1>'
```

Recommended reading:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)